# Upstream resolve breaks configuration

Tags: nginx

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 with the latest NGINX installed from [their official repository](https://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html):

```
$ sudo nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.11.8
```

I have the following defined in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/greendot.conf`:

```
# local dnsmasq
resolver 127.0.0.1;

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  '' close;
}

upstream websocket {
  zone elixr 64k;
  server greendot-elixr-1:4000 resolve;
  server greendot-elixr-2:4000 resolve;
}

server {
  listen 4000;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://websocket;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
  }
}
```

I have followed [the documentation on setting up DNS resolved upstream servers](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#server), and yet this configuration fails:

```
$ sudo nginx -T
nginx: [emerg] invalid parameter "resolve" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/greendot-nginx.conf:11
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

My goal is to simply create a server which uses DNS to periodically resolve its members. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _Additionally, the following parameters are available as part of our *commercial subscription:*_

Comment: Ugh, didn't catch that, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

The `resolve` parameter is part of nginx's commercial offering.

Here's the approach I ended up using:

```sh
server {
    ...

    # Use docker's internal nameserver
    resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=10s ipv6=off;

    location / {
        set $target myproject-web;
        proxy_pass  http://$target:8000;
    }
}
```

Note that:

- You have to define a variable (like $target), or nginx will query once, and use the resulting IP(s) forever (ignoring the resolver's 'valid' parameter).
- If the DNS query returns several IPs; nginx will round-robin to them.
- This approach may not work for you if you have more complex upstream requirements (backup endpoints, etc).